# how to access mobile device (windows mobile 6.0 or higher) drive using C# in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, mobile, windows-mobile, removable-storage

I would like to transfer a file from developer computer to mobile device which is a handheld terminal.
Also, I have an SD card which can be used as removable device. When I plugged in that SD Card into PC's slot, it's used as removable device and easily I can copy any file into SD Card using C# DriveInfo class.
But, when I plugged in the handheld terminal with USB cable to PC, I would like to reach folders and files in mobile device and want to do same things like copying and deleting any file I wanted...

The problem is that I can not reach mobile device because it's not seen as removable device when I used DriveInfo class of System.IO namespace so can not use that option.

Is there anyone around who came across the same problem or has knowledge for any solution, guys?

Comment: Can you copy files connected usb with mobile device center?

Comment: I can copy any files but yea, you are right! the only way to reach mobile device is to use RAPI or RAPI2 library as you mentioned below! I have achieved now! thanks a lot for the help, Reniuz!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I done few years ago this so I couldn't remember how at first...but remembered :) You can use [RAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920177.aspx) or even newer version [RAPI2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920150.aspx)(this version haven't used personally) library to achieve that.

Comment: +1 - Good ol' RAPI is the way to do it with Windows Mobile. Newer Windows Phone might be different but there is a clear change over.

Comment: Yes, RAPI is the way to go.  There are managed libraries for both out on CodePlex