# Transferring files from windows ce to desktop

Tags: c#, windows-ce

Is there a way to connect a Windows CE 6.0 device to a Windows 7 desktop PC without using activesync

Comment: [Yes there is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25916784/754438)

Comment: Except that RAPI uses ActiveSync/WMDC as its transport protocol...

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to just connect the two and have them communicate without some form of driver or application being written.  ActiveSync/WMDC is what Microsoft shipped "out of the box".  If you want to do what it does, then you have to replace it with another app or protocol, and it generally requires you to do both sides - a device app and a PC app.

What that would look like depends on how you intend to connect.  If you want to use USB, then you can likely use the CE RNDIS driver, so that the device shows up as an NDIS device, then use the desktop APIs to send network traffic to and from the device.  Of course you'll have to put an app or service on the device that knows how to take commands and do something with them.